# audio in internet explorer and cross-browser

Tags: html, audio, object, cross-browser, embed

I have an audio element in a webpage for a client and i have coded it as well as i can but i still can't get it to work on All browsers. I know cross browser and browser editions (i.e. internet explorer 6,7,8,9 ) with audio is tricky but there has to be an answer here. Can this be done and without needing browser plugins? Here is my current code.

```
<audio  preload="auto" autobuffer autoplay="autoplay"> 
<source src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.mp3"/>
<source src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.ogg" />
<source src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.wav" />
<source src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.au" />
<source src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.wma" />
<!-- browser compatibility fallbacks -->
<object>
<param name="autostart" value="true">
<param name="src" value="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.wav">
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
<param name="controller" value="false">
<embed src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.wav" controller="false" HIDDEN="TRUE" autoplay="true" autostart="True" type="audio/wav" />
<embed src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.mp3" controller="false" HIDDEN="TRUE" autoplay="true" autostart="True" type="audio/mpeg" />
</object>
<!-- End browser compatibility fallbacks -->
</audio>
```

Comment: I agree that Flash is the way to go here, possibly with a HTML 5 fallback. See e.g. http://jplayer.org

Comment: is there a flash player that has options to hide its controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox#Fallback_options) for some answers. I personally have made a page that uses the native `<audio>` element but provides a WMP fall back for the less tech savvy users that insist on using old deprecated software.